# react - absolute import for component show lint error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `SearchBox` component.

SearchBox.tsx

```
import React from "react";

import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

function SearchBox() {
  return (
    <Paper
      component="form"
      sx={{ p: "2px 4px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", width: 400 }}
    >
      <IconButton sx={{ p: "10px" }} aria-label="search">
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <InputBase
        sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1 }}
        placeholder="Search or start new chat"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search or start new chat" }}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

When I tried to import the component,

```
import SearchBox from "src/components/SearchBox";
```

it shows a lint error

```
Cannot find module 'src/components/SearchBox' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

[image]

but the project can be compiled and everything else works fine.

How can I solve this error?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
}
```

tsconfig.path.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.41",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the searchBox component in ‘src/component/searchbox.tsx’  from src/pages/home.tsx

So your import should be

import SearchBox from "../components/SearchBox";

You have to specify relative pathing

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you develop your app. If you are using create-react-app. Modify tsconfig.json

```
{

      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
      },
      "include": ["src"]
    }
```

then you can use

```
import SearchBox from 'components/SearchBox';
```

or

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

if this is what you want

```
import SearchBox from 'src/components/SearchBox';
```

if you don't use create-react-app, additional configuration needed.